# How to debug gunicorn application?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gunicorn

I have a `python gunivorn` application to serve as restful service. I am using `gunicorn app:app development --reload` to load the server. How can I enable debug model in this application? I am using `vscode` as IDE. And I am not sure how to debug it from this IDE.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a .sh file and run this.

Then with

```
gunicorn -b :8080 --log-level=DEBUG -w 4 file:app
```