# Gunicorn3's service unit file throws errors from a shell command defined in a python script

Tags: python, flask, systemd

I have a flask app that is now served by gunicorn3 + ngingx , the flask app uses a python script that uses an internal command to perform  a few actions and throws the result on to the html page .

Everything works fine, except that it seems gunicorn3 calls the flask app, it throws an error(perl based i think because of the internal command)  . I suspect a permission issue , but i'm not sure.

```
root@dev-elk-app01:/etc/init.d# service nexus status
● nexus.service - Gunicorn instance For Serving the flask App
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nexus.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-12-24 10:23:42 UTC; 29s ago
 Main PID: 2427 (gunicorn3)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nexus.service
           ├─2427 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/gunicorn3 --log-syslog nexus:app
           └─2451 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/gunicorn3 --log-syslog nexus:app

Dec 24 10:23:42 dev-elk-app01 systemd[1]: Started Gunicorn instance For Serving the Nexus App.
Dec 24 10:23:42 dev-elk-app01 gunicorn3[2427]: [2021-12-24 10:23:42 +0000] [2427] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
Dec 24 10:23:42 dev-elk-app01 gunicorn3[2427]: [2021-12-24 10:23:42 +0000] [2427] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (2427)
Dec 24 10:23:42 dev-elk-app01 gunicorn3[2427]: [2021-12-24 10:23:42 +0000] [2427] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Dec 24 10:23:42 dev-elk-app01 gunicorn3[2427]: [2021-12-24 10:23:42 +0000] [2451] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2451
Dec 24 10:24:06 dev-elk-app01 gunicorn3[2427]: Can't locate object method "ReadHistory" via package "Term::ReadLine::Stub" at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Shell
lines 1-15/15 (END)
```

To test the outcome , i stopped the service and used just the gunicorn  to host the app and that worked , no errors this time .

```
root@dev-elk-app01:/var/www/html/flask_nexus# /usr/bin/gunicorn3 --log-syslog nexus:app
[2021-12-24 10:37:18 +0000] [2592] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2021-12-24 10:37:18 +0000] [2592] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (2592)
[2021-12-24 10:37:18 +0000] [2592] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-12-24 10:37:18 +0000] [2595] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2595
```

Comment: *"Can't locate object method "ReadHistory" via package "Term::ReadLine::Stub""*: I think you need to install [`Term::ReadLine::Perl5`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine::Perl5) or [`Term::ReadLine::Gnu`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine::Gnu), the basic [`Term::ReadLine`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine) does not provide a `ReadHistory()` method

Comment: To provide more information on how and why `gunicorn3` called `perl`, try to start it with `--log-level=DEBUG`, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46386733/2173773) and then update your question with more details from the log output

Comment: Thanks for the updated debug output. It shows that the server executes "POST /result" just before the error. What is the content of the `result` script? Is it a perl CGI script?

Comment: it posts the result of the flask's python script ,which says log fetch failed . this log fetch is done by an internal tool that uses perl .   i logged into the server to make sure if the logs are present and they are . my flask app redirects the output of the python script to the HTML page on result.html

Comment: *"it posts the result of the flask's python script ,which says log fetch failed . this log fetch is done by an internal tool that uses perl "* : Please share more information about the CGI script and the internal tool. The error might be related to a restricted/changed include path when you run `gunicorn3` from the service relative to when you run it from the shell. Due to a change in the `perl` include path, the tool cannot find the correct `Term::ReadLine` modules

Comment: i edited the question to include the details , could you tell me how to find the include path in perl . ?  the internal tool is proprietary .

Comment: Thanks for the update. So it is probably `nsh` that is resonsible for the the error then? Is this a perl script or does it load another perl script? You can print out the perl include path  by running `perl -E 'say for @INC'`. Try to compare this with the path you get when running `gunicorn3` from the shell. Also check that you are running the same `perl` executable in the two cases. The output of `which perl` and `perl --version` is then useful

Comment: thank you for the responses :) . yes nsh is a perl script .the output of which perl is. "/usr/bin/perl" its the same one that shows up when running gunicorn3 from shell. however the systemd fails to run it . i assume its some permission problem .  i'll go over it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update : i have fixed the problem ,i had enabled verbose in all the scripts and it seemed gunicorn3 had trouble  with huge data that it was receiving from our internal perl script . as seen below with the BLOB data .

```
Dec 24 18:53:33 dev-elk-app01 gunicorn3[26598]: [1B blob data]
Dec 24 18:53:33 dev-elk-app01 gunicorn3[26598]: Can't locate object method "ReadHistory" via package "Term::ReadLine::Stub" at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Shel
Dec 24 18:53:34 dev-elk-app01 gunicorn3[26598]: Can't locate object method "ReadHistory" via package "Term::ReadLine::Stub" at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Shel
Dec 24 18:53:35 dev-elk-app01 gunicorn3[26598]: Can't locate object method "ReadHistory" via package "Term::ReadLine::Stub" at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Shel
Dec 24 18:53:36 dev-elk-app01 gunicorn3[26598]: Can't locate object method "ReadHistory" via package "Term::ReadLine::Stub" at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Shel
```

since the same script worked when we invoked from shell, i used TERM=linux in the systemd unitfile under the [service] tag, in an attempt to emulate the linux terminal and it worked . NO more errors ,the file fetch now happens successfully .